Object are dislocated when its render

some object are dislocated when Click on render the door handle object are dislocated

Looks like there are modifiers or something which have different settings for viewport and render. But without seeing those settings or inspecting the file this is just guesswork.

As @GordonBrinkmann says, we'll need to see your Blend file.  You can share it via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the full link on that page. Then edit your question here and paste the link into it.
